# Passing comma separated values to sp_executesql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, dynamic-sql, sp-executesql

I'm trying to use sp_executesql by passing CSV parameter.

When I use EXEC by passing constructed string, it returns me some data

```
declare @Accts nvarchar(100) = 'IntYTD,TotalIncome,PayoffYTD'
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = 'select sum(TotalBalanceMTD) from rptGL where FieldName in (''' + replace(@Accts, ',', ''',''') + ''') group by FieldName'
exec (@sql)
```

But when I use sp_executesql and pass the @Accts as parameter, it returns no data.

```
set @sql = 'select sum(TotalBalanceMTD) from rptGL where FieldName in (@values) group by FieldName'
declare @v nvarchar(max) = '''' + replace(@Accts, ',', ''',''') + ''''
exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@values varchar(max)', @values = @v
```

I can't find whats is wrong with this method

Comment: `IN` doesn't take parameters and `sp_executesql` doesn't do textual replacement. Your first query constructs the whole query dynamically. The second attempts to pass the clause as a parameter, but that won't fly. The basic problem is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/), along with solutions (in this case, a TVP might do nicely).

Comment: [Another solution using a split function in a subquery here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a8770fa9-6230-41d0-883f-947796db421c/use-parameterized-spexecutesql-with-in-clause?forum=transactsql)

Comment: @JeroenMostert, I was not aware of the limitation. I try to use split function or any other workaround. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you change the statement as following, it will get result.
For get some objective, you also can you charindex or split.

```
set @sql = 'EXEC(''select sum(TotalBalanceMTD) from #rptGL where    FieldName in (''+@values+'') group by FieldName'')'
declare @v nvarchar(max) = '''' + replace(@Accts, ',', ''',''') + ''''
exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@values varchar(max)', @values = @v
```

CHARINDEX:

```
 declare @Accts nvarchar(100) = 'IntYTD,TotalIncome,PayoffYTD'
 select sum(TotalBalanceMTD) from #rptGL where charindex(','+FieldName+',',','+@Accts+',')>0 group by FieldName
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but my intention is showing usage of sp_executesql versus EXEC. Also SPLIT is only available on 2016 (I'm on 2014). Thanks for posting an answer anyway. I'll wait for others to see if I can get an  answer close to my need